# How can I kill a process my Python executable started with sudo?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using this Python code to run a C++ executable:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import signal
import time

def trench():
    return subprocess.Popen(
        ['sudo', './Trench.out'],
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )

trench_display = trench()

time.sleep(5)

os.kill(trench_display.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

I've also tried this, but it didn't seem to make any difference:

```
trench_display.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

The issue is that when the Python code ends, the C++ executable continues to run. If I type any command and press enter, the terminal becomes glitchy and the program doesn’t seem to exit gracefully.

However, if I execute it directly from the terminal and use `kill -2 PID` or `Ctrl + C`, it exits gracefully. So, I believe the problem lies with Python’s subprocess.

I understand that this is a quirk of Python’s subprocess, but I’m wondering if there’s a way to fix it, without modifying the C++ source code?

Comment: We probably need to see what Trench.out does.

Comment: `os.kill()` doesn't work for something running with more privileges than you (neither does `kill -2` at the shell, for that matter). Thus, it's very deliberate that your code won't work because of the `sudo`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy beat me to the punch. I came to ask if your code is also running with elevated privileges

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah, good catch. maybe `subprocess.run(['sudo', 'kill', '-2', trench_display.pid])`?

Comment: Is there anything in your Python code that you _don't_ want to have the escalated permissions that `Trench.out` requires? If not, just run the whole thing under sudo; if you use sudo to start the Python interpreter, then you _don't_ need to use sudo to start `Trench`.

Comment: Executing with `sudo` does work! However, given the numerous OS operations, I’m paranoid about inadvertently causing any system issues...

Is there a way to make it work without resorting to `sudo`?

Comment: To turn that question around: Is there a way to make `Trench.out` work without resorting to sudo?

Comment: To be clear, there might be unprivileged approaches available, but they depend on the details of what `Trench.out` is and does. For example, if it tries to write to its stdout continually during execution, you could proxy that descriptor through your Python process to make the write fail when your Python process exits.

Comment: BTW, insofar as you want to be careful about side effects, `trench_display.send_signal` is a bit safer than `os.kill()`, insofar as the former won't try to operate if Python has reaped the child process and make the PID available for other programs to use. (Well -- I haven't actually checked the Python standard library's implementation, but if they _don't_ have that safeguard it's a bug and can/should be reported as such so it can be fixed).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `subprocess.run(['sudo', 'kill', '-2', str(trench_display.pid)])` exits Trench.out gracefully, however the terminal still ends up getting mangled and glitchy if I were to execute any subsequent commands

Comment: @N00B_141, that's still more reason to proxy trench's output through your Python process -- if it gets a FIFO fd instead of a real TTY handle, it can't change TTY settings through ioctl calls :) -- it still can change them through TERM sequences, but better-behaved programs don't send those either when they don't have a real handle for which `isatty()` is true.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Trench.out uses i2c which requires `sudo` privileges

Comment: @N00B_141, are you very, _very_ sure you can't delegate which accounts have access to the ioctl device nodes using udev rules? It would be unusual for a major Linux subsystem not to support that.

Comment: @N00B_141, ...indeed, i2c permissions _can_ be set that way. Start with https://www.ddcutil.com/i2c_permissions/

Comment: Granted, those docs just reference udev rules they don't package -- see https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil/issues/85 for an example of such rules.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not quite clear on what exactly u mean by a proxy. I'm a bit of a newb, so apologies... 

To give more insight into Trench.out, it basically uses `I2C`  to continuously stream data onto a display until an interruption takes place.

Comment: @N00B_141, what I mean by proxy is instead of using `subprocess.STDOUT`, use `subprocess.PIPE` and write your Python program to, for the five seconds you want it to operate, read from that pipe and write to Python's stdout. Then when you close that FIFO from the Python side it'll cause the next write that trench tries to perform to fail; if it's correctly written it'll exit when that happens.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that’s an insightful suggestion! However, your proposal of including the user in the i2c group is superior and completely resolves my problem. Huge thanks your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the real world you were able to resolve this by updating permissions to make `sudo` no longer necessary to perform i2c operations (which is certainly the best way to address this!), here's an alternate approach that fits within the bounds of the question:

```
import os
import subprocess
import signal
import time

def trench():
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(
        ['sudo', './Trench.out'],
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=p1.stdout)
    p1.stdout.close()
    return p2

trench_display = trench()
time.sleep(5)
trench_display.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

Note that `trench_display` no longer refers to `sudo ./Trench.out` but instead refers to `cat`, so when you kill it, the next time `Trench.out` tries to write to its stderr it'll get an EPIPE error and a SIGPIPE signal; unless it's explicitly trying to ignore both these things, this should cause Trench to exit even when it's running as a more-privileged user.

You could of course write Python code to copy from `p1.stdout` to the Python project's stdout -- using `cat` is a cheat to keep this answer short. :)

Answer (score 1):

The one and obvious answer is: just run `subprocess.popen` likewise  to run `sudo kill ...`, just as you did with to start the process in the first place. A system call made directly by your process won't ever have privileges to kill the higer privileged subprocess.